# ReactJS web application Permission error when deploy rty to build

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I'm stuck at deploying my reactJS web application to Heroku.
It worked fine on the local machine. I got problems with permission when Build section runs.
I don't know what did I wrong, everything else in this course works fine.

I tried to deploy the app with GitHub connection, but I got the same error.
I tried to run this code in terminal `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`, but I got another error (NPM... is not a command).

my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "contactkeeper",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Contact manager app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^12.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "clientinstall": "npm install --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "vinogitz",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "config": "^3.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.1.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash.template": "^4.5.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

my gitignore like this:

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
#client/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

-----> Build

```
       Running heroku-postbuild
       > contactkeeper@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_5e4bd7bd79fb3c0f84bb21cb820d7594
       > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
       audited 902208 packages in 13.316s
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       > client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_5e4bd7bd79fb3c0f84bb21cb820d7594/client
       > react-scripts build
sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.BWDxV/_logs/2019-07-22T11_55_03_878Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! contactkeeper@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contactkeeper@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.BWDxV/_logs/2019-07-22T11_55_03_893Z-debug.log
```

-----> Build failed

```
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       Love,
       Heroku
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Here's an example project of nodejs+react for heroku deployment : https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. the permission denied is not the perfect error message, but i found the solution.
I tried to ignore the node_modules folder in my client folder with .gitignore, but I didn't find the solution first time, so I just delete the sub folder node_modules from project. After that, I tried to deploy it again, and it's worked. So the real problem was that, the git add, git commit, git push commands pushed the node_modules sub folder to the repository.

PS.: The solution is: write node_modules/ instead of /node_modules in gitignore. With this the node_modules folders in a project (root folder or in a sub folder get untracked.)

Thanks!